# Build tools for php, html, css, js web app development

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, google-closure

What are some recommendations for a build tool that would allow me to upload changes to a web server or a repository and minify the js and css automatically, and possibly even run Closure compiler on the JavaScript?

I'm not worried about doing anything with the php code other than update with most recent changes although in the future would like to have phpdoc updated automatically.

Just wondering if there is some way to do all this other than an amalgam of scripts that run or have to be invoked every time?

Comment: [Maven for PHP](http://www.php-maven.org/) can do most of what you need. Haven't used it a while though, so don't treat this as an answer.

Comment: One of the more 'popular' build tools is [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I read this it sounds like you looking for a [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server.  You could leverage something like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or [phpUnderControl](http://phpundercontrol.org/) allowing you the flexibility to use almost any pre-build and deployment tools you want.   And builds can be scheduled or run as required.

A quick Google [search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=hudson+ci+%2Bphp) should get you started.

**OR**

If all the flexibility, automation and the bells and whistles are *not required* you could consider using [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/).  [This](http://www.buildmeister.com/articles/automating_the_php_deployment_process_with_phing,_dbdeploy_and_ftp) article is a good place to start.